# Is possible update ventoy through Linux when it was installed from the beginning through Windows 10?

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, bootloader, bootable-media, ventoy

To load an `.iso` image through the boot process through a pendrive (or usb flash drive) is very useful [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html)

I want to know if is possible, **and mostly safe**, accomplish the following scenario

- Is possible update ventoy through Linux when it was installed from the beginning through Windows 10?

Therefore exists currently a pendrive with Ventoy installed through Windows 10. But I want to know if is possible update Ventoy in the same pendrive through Linux - of course it in other laptop.

The pendrive has some .iso images and other custom directories and files.